# validator.w3.org finds error in an <a href="">

Tags: html, validation, url

```
Line 68, Column 58: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)
href="/xyz/index.php?m_id=6&news_id=12">More...</a>
```

What is the problem with the `&` character? I can't find a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `&` symbol to `%26` or `&amp;` and it should validate

Comment: no reason, its just I'm personally used to percent encoding. Answer edited :)